# Android Sqlite selection args[] with int values

Tags: android, sqlite

Have this line of code in the getEvents method of my DBHelper.

```
    int year, month, day;
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_EVENTNAME, KEY_DESCRIPTION,
            KEY_HOUR, KEY_MINUTE, KEY_DAY, KEY_MONTH, KEY_YEAR,
            KEY_REMINDER };
    Cursor c = database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, 
            KEY_YEAR + "=?"+ " AND " + KEY_MONTH + "=?" + " AND "+ KEY_DAY + "=?",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(year), String.valueOf(month), String.valueOf(day)}, 
            null, null, KEY_MONTH + " AND "
            + KEY_DAY);
```

It always returns nothing. When I remove the following

```
    int year, month, day;
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_EVENTNAME, KEY_DESCRIPTION,
            KEY_HOUR, KEY_MINUTE, KEY_DAY, KEY_MONTH, KEY_YEAR,
            KEY_REMINDER };
    Cursor c = database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, 
            KEY_YEAR + "=?",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(year)}, 
            null, null, KEY_MONTH + " AND "
            + KEY_DAY);
```

it runs correctly. What's the problem with my code? It seems like it doesn't accept multiple values as where clause.
Can any one help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error or an empty result set? did you check the values of month and day?

Comment: I did. year, month and day values are correct. That's why I don't see why this returns nothing.

Comment: So there is no error? cause the query looks really ok. please put a sample results from your second query, maybe there is a problem with the params.

Comment: I didn't get any error, it just returns 0 or nothing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is in the title: you are trying to pass integer values into the query, but what you actually end up with are *string* values.

This is a horrible design bug in the Android database API; you can use parameters only for strings.

Integer numbers do not have the formatting and SQL injection problems that string values would have, so you can just insert the numbers directly into the SQL expression:

```java
Cursor c = database.query(
    DATABASE_TABLE, columns, 
    KEY_YEAR  + "=" + year  + " AND " +
    KEY_MONTH + "=" + month + " AND " +
    KEY_DAY   + "=" + day,
    null, null, null,
    KEY_MONTH + "," + KEY_DAY);
```

(And the `orderBy` syntax was wrong.)

Comment: Never encountered this before, and I have been using the api since 2.2! That being said, I never tried storing Y/M/D values individually for Date..

Comment: Does this happen in all APIs? Did sqlite get smarter and just start handling `int = '4'`? I just found that a query that worked on a newer device wasn't working on an android kitkat device

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQLite itself; the Android framework uses a string array here. (Except for `execSQL()`, which cannot return result rows.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the syntax or logic. Try checking if the values of year, month, and day are correct.

Comment: I did. year, month and day values are correct. That's why I don't see why this returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help. After considering everything you suggested, I have finally found out the cause why it always returns nothing. The month value that I passed to this method was incorrect. It was a month ahead that's why it returns 0 for the current month. I'm sorry for the trouble. But all your answers are correct. It was a fault that I believe most or some have experienced. As a learning, I'd give extra care in looking into the values that I pass. Carefully looking into the flow of the values that are passed between methods saves time. I spent the whole night looking for the problem and just this morning after waking up I remembered the value that was passed into the method. Thanks again to everyone who gave the answers.