# How to update the table values

Tags: android, logic, android-sqlite

[image]

I have the table(shown in fig). I want to update the time column. I have the `medicine_id(second column)` how to update the different times depend upon the same `medicine_id(second column)`.

Also, I have four rows in my DB  when I updated time it should be two row means, I want to remove the other two rows with the particular `medicine_id`..

I have the following code for update:

```
if(mon) {
   for (int i = 0; i < dosage_per_day; i++) {
        mMedicineDbHelper.updateMedicines(new 
                             MedicineTime(row_id, time_InMillies[i]));
   }
}
```

My DB code:

```
public void updateMedicines(MedicineTime medicineTime) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ID, medicineTime.getId());
    values.put(MEDICINEID, medicineTime.getMedicine_id());
    values.put(TIME, medicineTime.getTime_in_millis());
    db.update(TABLENAME, values, MEDICINEID + " = ?", 
              new String[]{String.valueOf(medicineTime.getMedicine_id())});
    db.close();

}
```

It shows exception..
anybody help to solve this...

Comment: could you post the logcat for the issue?

Comment: well, the logcat is pretty straight forward, you are updating an id which is a primary key and is constrained to be unique. You should only update the time of your medicine

Comment: if your id column is a primary key then basically you don't need this line:

values.put(ID, medicineTime.getId());

Comment: @MariusM exactly it works..one more i want to insert the different time values at the same medicine_id what can i do.

Comment: You should just insert into your table the medicine_id with its time value. If your id - primary key column is auto-incremented then you only have to provide your time and medicine_id for insert.

As a side note, when you do an update, in the ContentValues object you only put the data to be updated. Buzz me if you need extra help.

Comment: @MariusM please read my post one more time i updated that..

Comment: @MariusM thank you so much...i solved this...first deleted the same  id's and insert again....

Comment: Well, that's fine if you solved your problem, maybe some optimizations would be required, pm me if you'd like to do that.

Answer (score 1):

For the original question asked you're executing the following code:

```
db.update(TABLENAME, values, MEDICINEID + " = ?", 
          new String[]{String.valueOf(medicineTime.getMedicine_id())});
```

For some reason on Android, converting numeric values to Strings and using them for selection args never works properly. See: [Android Sqlite selection args[] with int values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746149/android-sqlite-selection-args-with-int-values). The best way to do this is the following:

```
db.update(TABLENAME, values, MEDICINEID + " = " + medicineTime.getMedicine_id(), null);
```