# SQLite update query Android

Tags: java, android, sql

The table contains 4 columns : rowID , word , defintition , group_id

I want to change a certain row's word and definition . So here is my code (word is an object where the word , definition , id and the group_id are stored)

> ```
>    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
> ```

```
    values.put(KEY_WORD, word.getWord());
    values.put(KEY_DEFINITION, word.getDefinition());
    db.update(TABLE_WORDS, values, KEY_ID, new String [] {String.valueOf(word.getID())});
```

Can anyone tell me why it only creates a new line instead of changing the row under given ID ?

Answer (score 10):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_DATE, contact.getDate());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
   String id = "1";
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NOTIFICATION_STATUS,"canceled");
    db.update(TABLE_NOTIFICATION, values,COLUMN_NOTIFICATION_ID + " = ? ",new String[]{ String.valueOf(id) });
```

it will work as prepared statement.
this piece of code worked in my case .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Digvesh has the right idea, but because of [this limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746149/android-sqlite-selection-args-with-int-values), converting an int to a String to use as a selection arg will not work properly. Instead do this:

```
// assume: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_WORD, word.getWord());
values.put(KEY_DEFINITION, word.getDefinition());
int rowsUpdated = db.update(TABLE_WORDS, values, KEY_ID + "=" + word.getID(), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

this work for me, while db.rawquery didnot work.

output query

```html
String qu="UPDATE "+ DATABASE_TABLE_DATA + " SET "+isbookmark+" = "+status+" WHERE id = "+uid+";";
db.execSQL(qu);

output query :
UPDATE tabel_data SET `isbookmark` = 1 WHERE id = 2720271;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE instead of = operator.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_DATE, contact.getDate());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " LIKE ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this using `db.rawQuery` , i.e.

```
db.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ TABLE_WORDS + " SET "+ KEY_WORD + " = '"+word.getWord()+"' ,"+KEY_DEFINITION+"= '"+word.getDefinition()+ "' WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = "+word.getID(), null);
```

Here you don't need to create any `ContentValues`.

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) and [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) are details

Comment: I tried the same query with db.exec (). So what is the difference between those two methods ?

Comment: @user3199577 `execSQL(String sql)` and `execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)` both method do not return any data, but `rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)` returns data into `Cursor` object

Comment: @user3199577 Let me know if there any problem in above query.

Comment: This is the error
The method rawQuery(String, String[]) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: I don't see a reason to have to run the raw query and overcomplicate things unnecessarily. `update()` will work if you know how you're storing data in your DB and you structure your `update()` query properly. Please see my answer as this should work.

Comment: @anddev84  running the raw query is not complicating the things unnecessarily because 'update()` function internally execute the same sql query.