# UPDATE command not reflected

Tags: android, sql-update, android-sqlite

I know this question has been asked plenty of times but none of them seems to solve my problem. This is how the app looks.
[image]

Here is the function that executes the `update` command.

```
void incrementAttendance(Subject subject) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_PRESENT, subject.getPresent());
        db.update(TABLE_ATTENDANCE, values, KEY_ID + " = " + subject.getID(),null);
        db.close();
    }
```

This is the class where the table attributes are defined.

```
public class Subject {
    int _id;
    String _subjectName;
    int _present;
    int _absent;

    public Subject() {};

    public Subject(int id, String subjectName, int present, int absent) {
        this._id = id;
        this._present = present;
        this._absent = absent;
        this._subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    public Subject(String subjectName, int present, int absent) {
        this._present = present;
        this._absent = absent;
        this._subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setID(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this._subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    public void setPresent(int present) {
        this._present = present;
    }

    public void setAbsent(int absent) {
        this._present = absent;
    }

    public void incrementPresent() {
        this._present += 1;
    }

    public void incrementAbsent() {
        this._absent += 1;
    }

    public void decrementAbsent() {
        this._absent -= 1;
    }

    public String getSubjectName() {
        return this._subjectName;
    }

    public int getPresent() {
        return this._present;
    }

    public int getAbsent() {
        return this._absent;
    }

}
```

And this is how the command is invoked. The function is invoked when the Present button inside the list view is clicked.

```
public void myClickHandler(View v) {
        LinearLayout viewParentRow = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
        TextView child = (TextView)viewParentRow.getChildAt(1);
        child.setText("Present: " + 1);
        int id = Integer.parseInt(child.getTag().toString());
        subjects.get(id).incrementPresent();
        db.incrementAttendance(subjects.get(id));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I tried changing the update query to use args but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21166959/8618880) suggested that using integers in args won't work. I also tried to use `execSQL` but even that didn't work. I also uninstalled and re-installed the app each time I made a change. Most of the answers to similar questions suggested replacing `db.update(TABLE_ATTENDANCE, values, KEY_ID + " = " + subject.getID(),null);` with string args or using `execSQL` both of which didn't work. Here `TABLE_ATTENDANCE` is the name of my table. There is no error being generated in the logcat as well.

Other queries seem to be working fine.

Comment: for SQLite there is no difference between `where id = 5` and `where id = '5'`. Both are correct. In the 2nd case `'5'` will be implicitly converted to an integer. But your problem is different. Debug your code and check the value returned by `update()`, like `int result = db.update(TABLE_ATTENDANCE, values, KEY_ID + " = " + subject.getID(),null);`. If the value of `result` is `0` then no row was updated.

Comment: It returns `true`

Comment: I guess you mean it returns `1` which is the number of rows updated. If so then the update succeeded.

Comment: Yes. So you're right about it not being a problem with the query

Comment: update() updates 1 row. Maybe it does not update the correct row or you can't see in your UI the updated row.

Comment: @forpas I figured out the error. While retrieving all the subjects, for some reason, the cursor swapped the order of the columns of `present` and `absent`. I had not implemented the functionality for the absent button and hence could not catch this earlier. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Hope so below code solve your problem,

```
 public boolean incrementAttendance(Subject subject) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_PRESENT, subject.getPresent());
    return db.update(TABLE_ATTENDANCE, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(subject.getID())}) > 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it does not work. Also, I mentioned in the question that passing an integer in args causes an error. `subject.getID()` returns an integer.

Comment: you can use String.valueOf(subject.getID()) for it