# Where clause is not working for long in android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying for select statement in android `SQLite`
i am able to select all records in a cursor if i do below

```
String tableName = "Test";
String[] columns = {mobile};//mobile has a datatype number in db

Cusrsor c = m_sqlLiteDatabase.query(tableName, columns, null,null, null, null, null);

c.getCount(); // 11
```

but does not return any value if i add a conditon as below

```
long mobile = 123456;
    m_sqlLiteDatabase.query(tableName, columns, "mobile=" + mobile ,null, null, null, null);

c.getCount(); // 0
```

is anything i am doing wrong?
how to use long

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, that is the issue whereArgs are String[] and i want him to select long, i tried it that way also but didnt wored

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. Was going to suggest converting them to string, but that wouldn't work. According to this answer, I don't see why what you have wouldn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18749477/2308683

Comment: Are you sure that value is in the database?

Comment: Easy with the profanity on this site, but glad you figured out the problem

Comment: @cricket_007 Yup, Sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your query code line with this

```
m_sqlLiteDatabase.query(tableName, columns, " mobile = ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(mobile)} ,null, null, null);
```

Reference

```
query(String table, String[] columns, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having,
        String orderBy)
```

Comment: Thanks Umesh, But it is not going to work frnd because i am using a long variable in where clause , If i change it to string it will never work "String.valueOf(mobile)" , "mobile = " + mobile worked for me, I was comparing wrong column that's why it is failing

Comment: I don't think that there is any difference between  String.valueOf(mobile) and "mobile = " + mobile. As in both case mobile gona convert into string.

Comment: Yes there is difference, if i go with your example then it is internally going to be mobile="123456" in query but i want to do like mobile=123456 other wise it will not work on Number colume