# Why doesn't the question mark work in query function?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a method:

```
public int getCountOfFavoriteMovies(){

    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
        MovieDbScheme.NAME,
        null,
        MovieDbScheme.IS_FAVORITE + " = 1",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    );

    try{
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
    finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

it returns 7, but if i replace it with the following code:

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
    MovieDbScheme.NAME,
    null,
    MovieDbScheme.IS_FAVORITE + " = ?",
    new String[]{Integer.toString(1)},
    null,
    null,
    null
);
```

it returns 0 for some reason. **Why? Aren't they the same ?**

Comment: What result do you get if you use `MovieDbScheme.IS_FAVORITE + " = '1'"`?

Comment: @forpas i get 0

Comment: What is the data type of `IS_FAVORITE`?

Comment: Here's how i created my db: `db.execSQL("create table " + MovieDbScheme.NAME + "(" +
" _id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
MovieDbScheme.MOVIE_ID + "," +
MovieDbScheme.IS_FAVORITE +
")"
);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Datatypes In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) is a complicated concept and you must study it carefully to avoid issues like that.

You have defined the column `MovieDbScheme.IS_FAVORITE` without any data type and this means that it has no [type affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_affinity).

When you use `?` placeholders in the `selection` argument of the [`query()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method then these placeholders will be replaced by the values of `selectionArgs` as strings (so if you pass `1` it will be replaced by `'1'`).

This means that the comparison that takes place will be among a column with no affinity and a string.
In this case SQLite performs no affinity conversion and `1 = '1'` will return `false` because:

> for SQLite INTEGER values are always less than TEXT values

(from [Comparison Example](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#comparison_example))

What you should have done is define the column `MovieDbScheme.IS_FAVORITE` as `INTEGER` (or `BOOLEAN` if your SQLite version is 3.23.0+), in which case SQLite will perform affinity conversion and will compare both operands of the expression `1 = '1'` as integers.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WtSGHvB_).

So, uninstall the app from the device where you try your app, change your code to:

```
MovieDbScheme.IS_FAVORITE + " INTEGER"
```

in the `CREATE TABLE` statement and rerun.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are comparing it as string and not Integer, so your query will result in a WHERE condition like `IS_FAVORITE = '1'` instead of `IS_FAVORITE = 1`

I think you can embed integers in the selection param directly, cause they won't be able to harm with injections.

Probably related:
[Android Sqlite selection args[] with int values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746149/android-sqlite-selection-args-with-int-values)